# Xcode Autolayout and Rotation

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, autolayout, screen-orientation

I want to ask if it is better to have autolayout turned off when I want my application's views to adjust themselves properly to match the device's screen orientation when the user rotates the iOS device from portrait to landscape and vice-versa.

It's because when I have autolayout off, I can adjust my view's autosizing and masks manually via the size inspector. The views seem to adjust fine to match the screen orientation.

I have already tried this with autolayout on and when I rotate the device, the views don't put themselves in place properly for some reason. This only happens for some apps though(I guess it depends on the original placement of the views in portrait mode)

Am I just missing something like a feature or setting for the autolayout that fixes this automatically? Or is it better to go with autolayout turned off?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to use auto layout.  It sounds from your question like you have not done much work with autolayout or the constraints that are generated for you.  Yes, the generated constraints depend on the original placement of the view in portrait mode, but you will need to review and possibly change the constraints to make them work as you expect in landscape.

One of the key ideas driving auto layout is to specify how your views relate to each other so that iOS knows how to draw them in various circumstances, eg, rotating.

You mentioned that the views don't put themselves in place properly when rotated.  It sounds to me like the generated constraints are not setting the spacing from a leading or to edge to the super view for something important.

WWDC videos cover autolayout concepts but beware that how and when you specify constraints has changed in XCode 5, so be sure to review the XCode videos from WWDC '13 for those changes.

Comment: I see. I'm still pretty much a beginner with iOS programming. This definitely sheds some light.